# java.lang.ClassCastException: CLASS/Activity cannot be cast to MainActivity

Tags: java, android, android-layout, android-fragments

i just want to call this fragment after payment success status, but i don't know how to make it works.

Error on `((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.thank_you));`

```
 @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_order_thanks, container, false);

        ((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.thank_you));
        preferences = getActivity().getSharedPreferences("lan", MODE_PRIVATE);
        language=preferences.getString("language","");

        view.setFocusableInTouchMode(true);
        view.requestFocus();
```

The PaymentGatWay Class

```
public class PaymentGatWay extends Activity{
```

.
.
.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_instamojo_payment);
            sessionManagement = new Session_management(PaymentGatWay.this);
```

public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {
                Log.d(TAG, response.toString());

```
            try {
                Boolean status = response.getBoolean("responce");
                if (status) {
                    String msg = response.getString("data");
                    String msg_arb=response.getString("data");
                    db_cart.clearCart();
                    Bundle args = new Bundle();
                    Fragment fm = new Thanks_fragment();
                    args.putString("msg", msg);
                    args.putString("msgarb",msg_arb);
                    fm.setArguments(args);


                    FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();

                    FragmentTransaction ft = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                    ft.replace(R.id.contentPanel, fm)
                            .addToBackStack(null).commit();
                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
```

output error

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.gogrocer.tcc, PID: 9816
    java.lang.ClassCastException: gogrocer.tcc.PaymentGatWay cannot be cast to gogrocer.tcc.MainActivity
        at Fragment.Thanks_fragment.onCreateView(Thanks_fragment.java:51)
        at android.app.Fragment.performCreateView(Fragment.java:2508)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.moveToState(FragmentManager.java:1279)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.addAddedFragments(FragmentManager.java:2407)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.executeOpsTogether(FragmentManager.java:2186)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.removeRedundantOperationsAndExecute(FragmentManager.java:2142)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl.execPendingActions(FragmentManager.java:2043)
        at android.app.FragmentManagerImpl$1.run(FragmentManager.java:719)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:790)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:440)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `java.lang.ClassCastException`: `gogrocer.tcc.PaymentGatWay` cannot be
>   cast to `gogrocer.tcc.MainActivity`

change this:

```
((MainActivity) getActivity()).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.thank_you));
```

to this:

```
((PaymentGatWay) getActivity()).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.thank_you));
```

Or change it to:

```
getActivity().setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.thank_you));
```

Comment: it's working, but it create an issue, I think that's a simple way to do it, let me explain the details.

Comment: it's working, but it create an issue, I think that's a simple way to do it, let me explain the details.

All the calls `getActivity()).setTitle` uses MainActivity

is there a way to call it without changing from `MainActivity` to `PaymentGatWay`

Every class that works with MainActivity extends Fragment

While PaymentGatWay extends Activity

Comment: @AfonsoCardozoCruz i just add another option

Comment: It works too but, i'm using an method called `updateHeader()` that can't be resolved without `((MainActivity) getActivity())`

Comment: @AfonsoCardozoCruz Copy that method (`updateHeader()`) to `PaymentGatWay` OR copy to a base activity class and inherit all activities from it OR make an interface and implement it

Comment: Thank you, now I know what is happening, I will try to make those changes and put solution here

Answer (score 1):

You have to check which activity you are getting from getActivity().

```
  if(getActivity() is PaymentGatWay){
        (getActivity() as 
         PaymentGatWay).setTitle(getResources().getString(R.string.thank_you));
      }
```

Comment: i'll try your solution, but how can I check if getActivity() is PaymentGatWay

Comment: try above solution in that i have already added code to check activity.